# How do I get the value of the attribute value?

Tags: javascript

```
I want to show the value of the attribute as a parameter
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ufn6k25u/4/

Comment: Please elaborate your issue and fiddle link is also not working

Comment: Have you done any research? This isn't a hard problem with a quick search.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ufn6k25u/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you would like to obtain the `value` attribute of the div element. You can get it by utilising [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```js
myFunction = function (event) {
    document.getElementById('hi').value = event.target.getAttribute('value');
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myFunction(event)" value="50">
  click me
</div>

<input id="hi">
```